# Rails Controller Inheritance Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, controller, routes

I am trying to define a namespace as admin and my routes file is the following;

```
namespace :admin do
  root 'base#index'
  resources :boats
 end
```

So I have admin folder, and inside I have `base_controller.rb`;

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, :auth_admin

  def index

  end

end
```

and I created cars_controller.rb inherited from BaseController;

```
class Admin::CarsController < BaseController

        def index
            @cars = Car.all
        end

    end
```

So, like this I get error from the console;

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant BaseController):
  app/controllers/admin/cars_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

If I change instead of BaseController to ApplicationController, it works without a problem. Bur I could not figured it out why it gives such error.

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward; you're not in the module, so there's no `BaseController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant
>   BaseController):

Your `BaseController` is inherited from `Admin`, so you need to write `Admin::BaseController` instead of `BaseController`

```
class Admin::CarsController < Admin::BaseController
```